# How do I get the audio attached to a movieClip in adobe animate, to play along with the animation inside the movieClip

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, adobe

So the audio is attached to the movieClip and runs perfectly in the preview, but whenever I run the file the audio doesn't play with it, whole other audio does. Here is the relevant code, this is all done in HTML5 canvas using Javascript

```
                var root = this;

                root.Combo.Wire1.gotoAndStop(4)
                
                root.Combo.Bomb.gotoAndPlay(5);
                setTimeout(Explosion, 9500)
            
                function Explosion(){

                       root.House.gotoAndPlay(3);
                    
                }
```

All of the words listed but not delcared (combo, bomb, house, Wire1, etc.) are the instance names of movieClips that I set up in the Adobe UI. If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: **(1)** What format is the sound file you're bringing into the UI? Maybe Flash can handle it but is not supported by the browser **(2)** _"All other audio does play"_ are these files in a different folder?

Comment: We meet again you were on my other post on here I'm pretty sure. All the files brought in are .mp3, and I would assume not? Because when I brought them in I went "File>Import>Import to library" for all of the audio files, and from there i just dragged them onto the stage